# Google Play: Your device isn't compatible with this version. Error appears on all devices, but I can run the APK locally on phones

Tags: android, google-play

I can run the APK on the devices used for testing. But when I try to download from Google Play Store using the same devices I get the error.

Additionally Google Play Store says that the app is supported on 0 devices. Why?

Here is my Android Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mk.mojglas">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_screen"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:name=".FullScreenImageActivity" />
        <service
            android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mk.mojglas"
        minSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
//            minifyEnabled true
//            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }


    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The project wide Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using Android Studio 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

first .. if you dont need to restrict your app to specific screen size .. then remove this code `<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />`

second the target sdk must be at least Android 26 API.

---

take care your minSdk is 23 so the app will only be compatible with Marshmallow and higher :)

Comment: It's totally fine. Most of the devices have Android 7.0

Comment: make sure that you dont exclude any type of the devices from the device catalog in play console ..

Comment: also make sure that the version you try to install from play store is that one which you removed from it the screen supports tag :)

Comment: if you stuck .. try Live Chat with play console support team .. they will guide you with your app id.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Not many phones are 300DPI or lower anymore.

Comment: @vlatkorun is this a paid app?

Comment: Nope, it's free.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `packagingOptions` block in your Gradle config?

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose. I am not an Android developer. The app was created by other developer who is not available at the moment.

I am trying to put the app on Google Play Store.

If I remove the `packagingOptions` I get another error:
_Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/DEPENDENCIES_

Comment: Add `targetSdkVersion 27` right below `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: Update your `buildToolsVersion` to 27.0.3 and post the project-level Gradle as well.

Comment: I have edited my question with the project-level Gradle.

Comment: `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` is extremely outdated. It should be 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at your app online. The issue is something with how you are building your APK.

APKs are essentially just Zip files. If you look at your APK with a zip tool you can see it has a directory `/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar`.

The problem with this is that Google Play assumes any subdirectory under `/lib/` is used for holding native code ([see the documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#native-code-in-app-packages)). Because you have this directory, Google Play assumes you have native code for a platform called "commons-io-2.4.jar". Obviously no phones are of this native platform (it doesn't exist) so Google Play assumes no devices are compatible.

If you are putting this jar file in your APK in this directory, it isn't being used anyway. Change your build so it doesn't put this jar file here in your APK, and it should work.

By the way, the advice to remove the "`supports-screens`" element from other answers is really good. It doesn't cause the problem you are having, but you don't need it, and it might cause you other problems in future. Just take it out.